# How to get the raw response as a String in Spring webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux

```
return webClient//
            .post()//
            .uri(whatever.com)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)//
            .header("userId", CLIENT_ID)//
            .header("clientRequestId", requestId)//
            .bodyValue(bodyValue())//
            .retrieve()//
            .bodyToMono(Responseclass.class)//
            .block();
```

The above is working. But let's say I'm debugging and I just want to dump the raw response json into a String. How would I do that? toString() after retrieve doesn't work, and bodyToMono(String.class) didn't seem to work either. Either way it just printed the default toString value of the address of the pointer.

Comment: bodyToMono(String.class) -this should work, what is the issue with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Webflux WebClient you can get response as String like this:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://someurl.de/something");
String responseBody = client.get().retrieve().toEntity(String.class)
    .block().getBody();
```

In my German blog I wrote an article about using WebClient, there you will find more details around the code snippet above: 
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2021/01/reactive-webclient.html